# If Cells A1:C1= "No", All cells in the risk of the row will be blocked from input

Tags: vba, excel

Anyone know how to block cells from input (also gray it out) if for example cells A1:C1 = "No" then the rest of the row up to a say F1 is grayed out and blocked from input? I was hoping to do this in VBA but if there are other easier ways, please let me know! Thank you!

Didi

Comment: Look at coding an event handler for that worksheet, which would be in `Worksheet_Change`. Then your `Target` range would look for cells A1:C1 to all have "No" in the value and if so, would `Lock` the cells in D1:F1 and turn the text or background color gray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to show a different approach:

Put this in the sheet-code-tab:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Not (Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D1:F1")) Is Nothing) And Me.Evaluate("AND(LOWER(A1:C1)=""no"")") Then Me.Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

And to grey them out, best will be conditional formatting:

```
Range:   =$D$1:$F$1
Formula: =AND(LOWER($A$1:$C$1)="no")
```

- Using the conditional formatting allows to change the cells as you like without the need to alter the VBA code (this also will be faster)
- The VBA part itself, just sets the selected cell to A1 if A1:C1 is "No" and a range is selected which also includes any of the cells of D1:F1
- The `LOWER` can be skipped if you want it to be case sensitive

The only con is: if A1:C1 is "no" you still can *paste* a range to a cell (not any of D1:F1 directly) which also include the *locked* cells.
The biggest pro is: this also works for shared workbooks (as there is no need to lock/unlock sheets)

**EDIT**

If the cells need to be protected then something like this will do:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim a As Boolean
  a = Me.Evaluate("AND(LOWER(A1:C1)=""no"")")
  If a <> Me.Range("D1").Locked Then
    Me.Unprotect
    Me.Range("D1:F1").Locked = a
    Me.Protect
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Dirk! I'll take a look. My main concern is that I don't want any of the grey out cells to allow any inputs so that it can be completely locked out. :)

Comment: @DidiZhang I added an **edit** to lock the cells. (this does not grey out the cells).

Answer (score 0):

as was mentioned in the comments, look to use a workbook change event with the following sub

```
Sub test()
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "no" And Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value = "no" And Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Value = "no" Then
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:F1").Interior.Color = RGB(220, 220, 220)
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:F1").Locked = True
Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect
End If
End Sub
```